# C++ Do while loop advice

Tags: while-loop, do-while

So at my college we haven't covered do while loops yet so I wanted to try one out before we do but I am running into an issue with it, I want the program to carry out different functions based on the users input, A carries out an addition, B a subtraction and C exits the program.
The program I have wrote with a do while in it carries out these functions one after the other regardless of what the user has input and I am unsure how to get this working properly.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You have more while-loops here than do...while loops, and all of your while loops are next to useless. You may want to look up how while loops work.

Comment: do while is not the correct way you are using it. It should be used as input validation. for example: do { cout << "enter choice" cin >> choice }while(choice != 'A' || choice != 'B' || choice !=  C); this re-asks the user if they enter a wrong choice that is not part of the menu

Comment: You also have excess while-loops and semi-colons at the end? You only put semi-colon for do-while not normal while loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things to note. You have user entering a character for a choice, so make userChoice a character. Notice how the do-while is used for input-validation in this case. I changed the extra while loops with semi-colons at end to condition statements. You can substitute the if and else ifs with switch, "menu driven program". Here is a working program that you want. If you want the do-while around the whole condition statement and not use it as input validation then have it around all the condition statements and check while it is not C.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char userChoice;

  int vaulue1;
  int vaulue2;

  int addtionValue;
  int subtractionValue;

  cout << "Choice A: will preform an addition" << endl;
  cout << "Choice B: will preform a subtraction" << endl;
  cout << "Choice C: will quit\n" << endl;


    do
      {
        cout << "Enter your choice\n" << endl;
        cin >> userChoice;
      } while(userChoice != 'A' && userChoice != 'B' && userChoice != 'C');

    if(userChoice == 'A')
      {
        cout << "Addition\n" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the first value you want to add\n" << endl;
        cin >> vaulue1;
        cout << "Please enter the second value you want to add\n" << endl;
        cin >> vaulue2;

        addtionValue = vaulue1 + vaulue2;
        cout << "The addtion answer is " << addtionValue << endl;
      }

    else if(userChoice == 'B')
      {

        cout << "Subtraction\n" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the first value you want to subtract\n" << endl;
        cin >> vaulue1;
        cout << "Please enter the second value you want to subtract\n" << endl;
        cin >> vaulue2;

        subtractionValue = vaulue1 - vaulue2;
        cout << "The subtract answer is " << subtractionValue << endl;
      }

    else if(userChoice == 'C')
      {

        cout << "Exit ";
        return -1;
      }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me with this, it seems I was confused with the purpose of a do while and how to properly implement it, your answers have helped to clear it up.

Comment: @M.Stran94 please mark this answer as accepted if you believe this answered your question, so others can use this as well! No problem!

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use only one "while" - just first while is correct
2. other "whiles" are empty loop; clean them
3. it's better to use "switch - case"

while you enter `A` as input your method wants to give `A` another one